# How to add IIS web project to tfs source control

Tags: iis, tfs

I have installed and configured TFS server 2012 in my machine. I have an classic asp web application hosted in iis 7.0. I want to map this IIS application to TFS source control.

Comment: Did you find any way to do it? Because I have a same situation.How to map an IIS web application to TFS source control?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to develop your application in classic ASP while using TFSVC.

I think the best solution is to use the TFS Power Tools (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) and the Windows Shell Extensions to get access to TFSVC directly from the Windows Explorer.

You will be able to do get and checkin operations directly from Windows Explorer thanks to this plugin.